# iOS: reload table and change map region on mother view controller from popover

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, uipopovercontroller, mkmapview

I have a ViewController with a TableView and a MapView and a button which opens a PopOver with another TableView. There the user can select some positions which should be shown on the Table and the MapView in the mother ViewController.

I have a function which calculates the table data and draws those annotations in the mother ViewCoontroller. This is called from the child ViewController by initiating it:

```
MotherViewController * MVC = [[MotherViewController alloc] init];
[MVC calculateresults];
```

The selected data is then passed back via protocol and the function calculates the proper results. However the table won't reload because [self.TableView reloaddata] doesnt work when the PopOver is still opened. If I close the PopOver and start the function directly on the mother ViewController everything works fine.

Tried already this, but doesn't work:
[iPad SplitViewController: Reloading the root view controller's tableview from the detail view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481724/ipad-splitviewcontroller-reloading-the-root-view-controllers-tableview-from-th)

How can i update a Map and a Table in a mother ViewController while a PopOver is opened?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is failing is not that "[self.TableView reloaddata] doesnt work when the PopOver is still opened." The reason is that `self` is a different `self`. You are saying:

```
MotherViewController * MVC = [[MotherViewController alloc] init];
[MVC calculateresults];
```

So `MVC` is *not* the MotherViewController whose view you see behind the popover. It is a *different* MotherViewController - the one you just created with `alloc`. So the MotherViewController that you see behind the popover never gets any message, so it does nothing.

Naturally when you do this directly in *that* MotherViewController, it works.

Instead of saying

```
MotherViewController * MVC = [[MotherViewController alloc] init];
```

You need to arrange for your popover to have a reference to the *already existing* MotherViewController.

Comment: okay i was so stupid to call my mother ViewController really MotherViewController in this example which makes it off course difficult to explain... But the ViewController which is the mother ViewController is in reality called MotherViewController, so the reference is correct. I receive even NSLogs from the calculateresults function when I call it from the PopOver.

As I already said the function in the mother VC gets called, its just that the Map and the Table don't update. What else could be wrong? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You are just making me repeat myself. Try to listen and believe me. You do not understand what `alloc] init]` does. Yes, the view controller is really called MotherViewController and you receive NSLogs. But in those NSLogs if you log `self` you will see that I'm right: the MotherViewController who you are talking to and who is sending you the log messages is not the same MotherViewController that's sitting there behind the popover. You have *two* MotherViewControllers, because `alloc` creates a second one.

Comment: okay. i was just thinking that i didn't explain myself properly and someone could misunderstand me... now if we figured out the problem how can i solve it? how can i call a method from another class without initiating it before?
ps: when i log self in the motherVC i will get 0x8059af0. when i call the function from the popOver i also get 0x8059af0.

Comment: That's an architectural issue. You have to plan ahead! The problem of getting a reference from one instance to another is very tricky, but it is the heart of Cocoa programming. See this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_instance_visibility